# Is Ada.Calendar time zone aware?

Tags: ada

I am working with some legacy Ada 95 code where the original developers defined a timestamp as follows:

```
type Timestamp_Time_Type is
record
  Month   : Month_No_Type  := Min_Month;
  Day     : Day_No_Type    := Min_Day;
  Hours   : Hour_No_Type   := Min_Hour;
  Minutes : Minute_No_Type := Min_Minute;
  Seconds : Second_No_Type := Min_Second;
end record;
```

The lack of the year is not my concern here, that is because the timestamps on the messages being received lack a year field.

What I'm trying to determine, is why they would not just use the Time type defined in Ada.Calendar. The only reason I could think of is that perhaps the Time_Of and Split subprograms defined in this package only convert to and from the epoch value using GMT. So, do the Time_Of and Split subprograms automatically take into account the machine's time zone, or does the programmer need to write code to convert to GMT first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ada95 is almost certainly not timezone aware.The LRM simply says of the time type...

"A value of the type Time in package Calendar, or of some other implementation-defined time type, represents a time as reported by a corresponding clock."

The package Ada.Calendar.Time_Zones was introduced in Ada 2005.

Answer (score 0):

For a possible answer to the question of why the program doesn't use `Ada.Calendar.Time`: `Ada.Calendar.Time` is a private type whose representation is not specified by the language.  It is therefore not suitable for writing it to a file or socket if it could be read by Ada code built by a different compiler, or even by a later version of the same compiler if they decide to change the representation, or by a non-Ada program.  If `Timestamp_Time_Type` is something written directly to a file or socket, that would be a very good reason for not using `Time`.  (Writing integers can cause its own portability problems because of byte ordering, but it looks like all the integers here will fit in a byte.)

Another reason could be efficiency.  `Split` takes a little time, and it may be desirable to do the split only once and then pass the resulting fields around, rather than use `Split` every time the program needs the fields.

Without knowing more about the program, however, this is all speculation.

Comment: Well, after digging further, it turns out that it is in fact, converted into a Time using Ada.Calendar.Time_Of, with some extra checks to determine the year first. This is done to calculate the difference between the received time stamp and the system time. It seems that it may have never been considered that the message might come from another time zone.

If the representation of Time is not specified by the language, does that mean it is possible that it's not an epoch time?

Comment: In GNAT 3.16, Time’s representation was based on the Unix epoch. Somewhere before GNAT 5.02, probably in 2005, this was changed; from the code, the GNAT epoch is now 136 years earlier (I think; this is *very* confusing, see a-calend.adb:204, Epoch_Offset, and :907, To_Ada_Time).

Comment: @Ogre The _representation_ of `Time` (i.e. what bits are present in a `Time` object and what they mean) is an implementation detail that you're not supposed to care about.  That's why it's problematic to use it in a way that depends on the bits having a certain representation, such as `Unchecked_Conversion` or writing it externally.  I'm simply suggesting this as a reason why your legacy program didn't use it, and instead used something more portable.  This reason has nothing to do with time zones or epochs, so please don't get fixated on those.

Comment: The GNAT epoch is 2150-01-01, which is 180 years later than the Unix epoch, and is more-or-less half-way between the LRM limits of 1901-01-01 and 2399-12-31 (I’m less than confident about the latter, the ARM only explicitly specifies the year).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting fixated, just trying to understand as much as I can for future design considerations.